# Pandas Worked, Now It Doesn't

Tags: python, pandas, pip, anaconda, spyder

I am currently taking FlatIron Academy's Data Science Bootcamp Prep Course which operates in Python. In one of the lessons, the goal is to display a map with a marker on specific locations. For example, the code to put a marker on Buenos Aires is:

```
coordinates = [-34.6037, -58.3816]
ba_latitude = coordinates[0]
ba_longitude = coordinates[1]
!pip install folium
import folium
buenos_map = folium.Map([ba_latitude, ba_longitude])
buenos_map
```

At this point I should mention, I use Python on Spyder through Anaconda. So perhaps using `!pip` here was my first mistake.

Now, when I ran this code for the first time in Spyder, nothing fancy happened--just the file name for an image file came up but no image was displayed (I don't really know where that image file was created or anything about it, and I am curious if it is possible to display an image or interactive map like that in Spyder, but that's not the focus of this question right now). But when I ran the exact same code in a Jupyter Notebook, launched through Anaconda as well, the code worked perfectly and all was fine: an interactive map popped up with the marker where it was supposed to be.

The next day, the lesson included importing Excel files into dictionaries. The code used in the example is:

```
import pandas as pd
file_name = './cities.xlsx'
travel_df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
cities = travel_df.to_dict('records')
```

and my own version of the code is:

```
import pandas as pd
corridor_cards_df = pd.read_excel('./Corridor Cards June 2019.xlsx')
ccd = corridor_cards_df.to_dict('records')
for i in range(len(ccd)):
    print(i)
    print(ccd[i])
    print("\n")
```

since I wanted to iterate through each item and display it. This also worked perfectly both in Spyder and in Jupyter.

The issues started to happen when I got to the lesson on Plotting Data. This is what the lesson says:

"There are various Python visualization tools we can use to display our data. In this lesson, we will be using Plotly, as it produces nice looking graphs and is easy to work with.

We can easily download the `plotly` library with the use of `pip`.

> Pip is a package management system that allows us to easily download and install libraries written in Python.  If you are working on Learn, we have already installed pip for you.  We will not walk through installing pip here, however you can find instructions on installing pip [for Mac](http://softwaretester.info/install-and-upgrade-pip-on-mac-os-x/) or [for Windows](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=instally+pip+windows) online.  Also, if you are familiar with working with a terminal and have `easy_install`, you can run `sudo easy_install pip` from the terminal."

I thought to myself, I might as well install pip, so I followed the link for Windows, clicked on the video by KIJUKA and also clicked on the link in the description of the video. At this point I saw that I actually do not need to install pip since I am using Python version 3.6.5. But, whenever I would try to upgrade pip inside Spyder using `python -m pip install -U pip` I would get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. At this point I realized there might be differences between Python, Anaconda, and the Anaconda Powershell Prompt, and also a difference between Pip and Conda. I think I managed to properly install Pip using Conda (though at this point my memory is really fuzzy and I can't find a log of all my commands in the Conda Powershell Prompt). The next thing I remember doing is updating Anaconda and all the apps inside of it including Jupyter and Spyder to the most up-to-date versions. I then received a message that my application Spyder launch may have produced errors so I reverted it back to version 3.2.8.

I don't know at which stage of the process this happened, but now when I import pandas and call methods from it, I always receive an Attribute Error. For instance, when I run the code above I get: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_excel'`. I have multiple files with the title pandas.py and they are not all the same. None of them list any method called `read_excel` and even when I use `folium` I get the error: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'`.

I honestly feel so computer illiterate and have no clue what happened, where to look for answers, what I did wrong etc... Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all anaconda comes with its own set of modules. You can use conda to install packages and you can also use pip for that. When I install packages in anaconda I make sure I am using the anaconda prompt. Using anything other than that may produce errors. The solution according to me would be open anaconda prompt and try

```
conda install pandas
```

And then try to run the code again. If that doesn't work, try

```
pip install pandas
```

If nothing works, try uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda but this time make sure to use anaconda prompt to install packages.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Not sure why it didn't work before, but I feel like I definitely did `conda install pandas` in the anaconda powershell prompt before and it didn't work. But now it did and I am very relieved! Sometimes the most frustrating problems have the simplest solutions :)